# Google App Engine and Stackdriver Debugging: /tmp/debugger-breakpoints file not found

Tags: google-app-engine, stackdriver, php-7.2

I'm trying to integrate the Stackdriver debugger so I can figure out why my app isn't working as intended. I've followed the setup instructions here:

https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/setup/php#gae-flex

However, my Cloud Console says the app isn't ready for debugging and when I browse to my app I see this in the logs:

```
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/tmp/debugger-breakpoints): failed to open stream: No such 
file or directory in /srv/vendor/google/cloud-debugger/src/BreakpointStorage/FileBreakpointStorage.php on line 94"
```

Comment: What PHP version are you using? Stackdriver Debugger is available for PHP versions 7.0 or greater. Did you enable [Stackdriver Debugger API](https://cloud.google.com/debugger/api/)? You can try to select your source code [manually](https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/source-options#app_engine). Also, make sure you do not use Standard APP Engine. The Stackdriver Debugger agent for PHP is not supported in [App Engine standard environment](https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/setup/php#gae-standard) yet.